# img inside floated div - div does not stretch with image width

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am facing a strange situation in Firefox. My HTML setup is as follows:

```
<div class="tab">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="some-url" class="image" /> 
    </div>
</div>

.tab {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%; // The document width, 
    overflow: auto;
}

.imageContainer {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 50%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The original image's width is `400 px`, and when the `height:100%`on the image applied, it increases to 600 px. Normally, the container div should stretch to 600 px along with the image. On Firefox (20.0.1), the `imageContainer div`'s width is set at 400 px, however the image stretches. The `max-width:50%` yields a maximum value of 700 px in my test case.

On Chrome and IE, this works without any problems. How to fix this?

Edit: here is a jsfiddle expalining the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/dSr7s/

Comment: any jsfiddle?  could use it

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I've edited the question, added one at the bottom

Comment: well, looks like the image is rendered first and then the container gets the size, with min-width: 50% / max-width: 50% it worked but i dont think this is good for you, i will try other workaround.

EDIT: And i think that the firefox behaviour is the right one, because the image width is 427 so it fills only 427 from the container that has max-width 600px

Comment: removing float:left from .imagecontainer works but i dont know if it work for you.

Comment: Well I need that float: left, because I need to place other content on the right side of the image. min-width: 50% / max-width: 50% is no good for me as well.

Comment: Looks like Firefox doesn’t want to stretch the container element because of `overflow:hidden` – do you need that for what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Well strangely, on jsfiddle if I remove the overflow:hidden, that solves the problem, but on my website that changes nothing, the whole image would be visible but the div wouldn't strecth. It may be caused by the rules of the css reset I am using, I'm checking that now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to fix that?

Comment: I managed to fix it by removing the overflow: hidden. Does that work for you?